# Correct way to construct view when using nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having difficulty understanding how I should build my view to ensure the update of my project model also updates the appropriate related records

I have the following models: Project, User and AuthorisedUser

Each project has a list of authorised users who are permitted access, and the selection of authorised users is made from a drop-down picklist of all users within the project edit view. 
I'm keen to make use of as much of the Rails 'magic' as possible, so my understanding is that in order for the project.update method to deal with saving the collection of authorised_users for the project, I need the following associations:

```
(Project Model)
has_many :authorised_users
has_many :users, through: :authorised_users
accepts_nested_attributes_for :authorised_users

(User Model)
has_many :authorised_users
has_many :projects, through: :authorised_users

(Authorised User Model)
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :user
```

What I'm having difficulty  understanding is how to construct my view such that the authorised users (i.e. those selected from the list of all users) will appear as required in the params presented to the controller- I think I need somehow to include a reference to the AuthorisedUser model, but I've only been able to find examples of this where the fields_for helper is used, for example:

```
  = project_form.fields_for :authorised_users do |auf|          
      - selected = @project.authorised_users
      = auf.label :user_id, 'Authorised Users'
      = auf.collection_select('authusers', User.all, :id, :username, {:prompt => 'Blah', :selected => selected}, {multiple: true, class: 'form-control'})
```

Although this does result in the appearance of authorised_user_attributes within the controller params, this isn't quite right since the block will (obviously) repeat the selection for every authorised user- I just want one selection box to appear, from which selected users can be saved as 'authorised' against the project

This probably isn't as difficult as I seem to be making it, but I'd be grateful for some clarity on the best approach- for example:

Can this be done implicity by Rails as part of the project.update, or must I iterate through the collection of authorised_users in the project controller, manually updating the associated records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier than what you're trying to do.

You don't need `accepts_nested_attributes_for :authorised_users` in the Project model, since you want only to update `user_ids`. Therefore, you don't need `fields_for`.

```
- selected = @project.authorised_users
= project_form.label :user_ids, 'Authorised Users'
= project_form.collection_select :user_ids, User.all, :id, :username, {:prompt => 'Blah', :selected => selected}, {multiple: true, class: 'form-control'})
```

Don't forget to add `user_ids: []` to permitted parameters and remove any unused parameters from the first implementation.

Comment: Thanks- this looks helpful, I'll try this approach. As a side note-this answer contains one of the things I struggle with getting my head around in Rails- The first parameter in the collection_select is ':user_ids' (with a leading colon), whilst the declaration of the user_ids as permitted parameters is 'user_ids: []' (i.e. trailing colon and array). Can someone explain the reason why using the same 'user_id' declaration for both is not appropriate? Thanks

Comment: @David, you can't use `:user_ids` in controller, because you need to explicitly specify array in permitted parameters. Notation `params.require(:project).permit(:title, user_ids: [])` just tells "`project` key should necessarily be in params (or you'll get the error), and inside its value we take only 2 parameters, which keys are `title` and `user_ids`, and value of `user_ids` is array, don't treat it like a string"

Comment: Feel free to comment here if something is wrong with my answer, or accept it if all goes well :)